# Android4 emulator usually does not start activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-emulator

I use `eclipse`. When I try to `run/debug` my App on emulator with Android +4, usually I have to try twice! But when I use other emulators ( before Android 4, for example 2.3.3, ...) this does not occur. When I use Android 4 emulator and forced to try twice I can see these lines in `console`:

> Android Launch!
>   adb is running normally.
>   Performing com.example.test.MainActivity activity launch
>   Automatic Target Mode: Several compatible targets. Please select a
>   target device.
>   Uploading Test.apk onto device
>   'emulator-5554'
>   Installing Test.apk...
>   Success!
>   Starting activity com.example.test.MainActivity
>   on device emulator-5554

And in normal tries I can see this line below of above lines in console:

> ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   cmp=com.example.test/.MainActivity }

It seems that my application installs correctly but I have to start that from launcher or I have to try `run/debug` again. Why usually this occurs and how I can avoid that?